# PhoneGap: Email Composer fails if alert fires first (iOS)

Tags: cordova

I find that if I trigger an alert either through a help button or a 
automated check that my email composer function will fail to launch. 
But if I go through the app without launching any alerts, the email 
will work fine. Seems to me more like a JS issue rather than an issue 
specifically with the plugin but I am pretty new to this. Any ideas on 
what may be the source of my issue?  I mean the email issue, not the 
dozen or so other issues I probably have below :) 
Thanks 
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer ended up being that I was overwriting everything and needed to use jquery and just focus it inside the body tags.

```
$('body').html("");
$('body').append("foo"); ...
```